# Ограничение поворота объекта

Tags: c#, unity3d, 3d, объекты

Как в Unity банально ограничить поворот объекта? Например, имеется обычный цилиндр, который поворачивается вокруг оси Х. Как сделать, чтоб при повороте на 30 градусов, он дальше не поворачивался?

Comment: если градус >= 30 то делаем то то...

Answer (score 1):

Зависит от того, каким образом вы осуществляете вращение. Если назначаете поворот напрямую, помощником вам тут будет [Mathf.Clamp](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/530/ScriptReference/Mathf.Clamp.html).
Этот метод "зажимает" значение между минимальным и максимальным значениями, переданными в параметры. Т.е. значение, которое вернёт метод не будет выходить за указанные границы.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(transform.rotation.x <= 30){
    rigidbody.AddRelativeTorque(1, 0, 0);
}
```

Все просто. Не забудьте повесить на цилиндр компонент `Rigidbody`
Если нужно сделать при помощи Transform, меняем `rigidbody.AddRelativeTorque` на `transform.Rotate`

Answer (score 0):

Привет! Вам не обходимо будет приьегнуть к некоторым вычислениям, сам когдато бился этой штукой, хоть и использровал пример кода.
Вам необходимо сделать следующее:

Взять некое направление объекта, например `_previewObject.transform.up` локальное направление объекта по оси Y в вверх и потом подсчитывать градусы, сравнивая с глобальной(мировой) осью Y, затем ограничивать эти градусы и применять к объекту.
Пример кода:

```
void RotateObject(Vector2 _delta){ // дельта - это значени на которое передвинули мышь или палец
    Vector3 up = _previewObject.transform.up; // берём направление объекта по оси Y вверх
    _previewObject.transform.RotateAround(_focusOnPosition, up, -_delta.x); // крутим объект вокруг оси Y без ограничений

    float angle = Vector3.Angle(Vector3.up, up); //считаем угол между моровой осью и осью просматриваемого объекта
    angle *= Vector3.Cross(Vector3.up, up).x > 0 ? 1 : -1; // приводим градусы(угол)  к значениям от -180 до +180, т.к. Vector3.Angle выдает только положительные значения
    float newAngle = Mathf.Clamp(angle - _delta.y, -90, 90); // ограничиваем угол, от -90 до +90, тут свои значения можете вписать
    float deltaAngle = newAngle - angle; // вычисляем новый дельта угол, на какое количество градусов удалось поернуть объект.
    _previewObject.transform.RotateAround(_focusOnPosition, Vector3.right, deltaAngle); // крутим, собственно, объект по оси Х
}
```

P.S. Может быть код выглядит как-то громоздко, но за то работает как надо!